# Windows IoT Core Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10-iot-core

Is it possibe to paire a bluetooth device under Windows IoT Core programmatically? And how do I? Would be perfect to show aviable devices.

The only way I know is http://minwinpc:8080

Comment: Please refer to another question of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35956624/uwp-unpaired-paired-bluetooth-devices) for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small wrapper for pairing bluetooth devices using observable collections of paired and unpaired devices. You can easily bind those to list boxes on your view.

**BluetoothSerice.cs**

```cs
public class BluetoothService
{
    private TaskScheduler _threadContext;
    private DeviceWatcher _watcherPaired;
    private DeviceWatcher _watcherUnpaired;

    private ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation> _pairedDevices;
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation> PairedDevices
    {
        get { return _pairedDevices; }
        set { _pairedDevices = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation> _unpairedDevices;
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation> UnpairedDevices
    {
        get { return _unpairedDevices; }
        set { _unpairedDevices = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler RefreshCompleted;

    public BluetoothService()
    {
        _threadContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        PairedDevices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();
        UnpairedDevices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInformation>();
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        PairedDevices.Clear();
        UnpairedDevices.Clear();

        var selectorPaired = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true);
        _watcherPaired = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(selectorPaired, null, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);

        var selectorUnpaired = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false);
        _watcherUnpaired = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(selectorUnpaired, null, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);


        _watcherPaired.EnumerationCompleted += _watcherPaired_EnumerationCompleted;
        _watcherPaired.Added += _watcherPaired_Added;
        _watcherPaired.Removed += _watcherPaired_Removed;

        _watcherUnpaired.EnumerationCompleted += _watcherUnpaired_EnumerationCompleted;
        _watcherUnpaired.Added += _watcherUnpaired_Added;
        _watcherUnpaired.Removed += _watcherUnpaired_Removed;

        _watcherPaired.Start();
        _watcherUnpaired.Start();
    }

    public async Task<DevicePairingResult> PairAsync(DeviceInformation device)
    {
        return await device.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None);
    }

    public async Task<DeviceUnpairingResult> UnpairAsync(DeviceInformation device)
    {
        return await device.Pairing.UnpairAsync();
    }

    private void _watcherUnpaired_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
    {
        InvokeThread(() =>
        {
            var matched = UnpairedDevices.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == args.Id);
            if (matched != null)
            {
                UnpairedDevices.Remove(matched);
            }
        });
    }

    private void _watcherUnpaired_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        InvokeThread(() =>
        {
            var matched = UnpairedDevices.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == args.Id);

            if (matched != null)
            {
                UnpairedDevices.Remove(matched);
            }

            UnpairedDevices.Add(args);
        });
    }

    private void _watcherUnpaired_EnumerationCompleted(DeviceWatcher sender, object args)
    {
        _watcherUnpaired.Stop();

        RefreshCompleted?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    private void _watcherPaired_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate args)
    {
        InvokeThread(() =>
        {
            var matched = PairedDevices.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == args.Id);
            if (matched != null)
            {
                PairedDevices.Remove(matched);
            }
        });
    }

    private void _watcherPaired_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation args)
    {
        InvokeThread(() =>
        {
            var matched = PairedDevices.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == args.Id);

            if (matched != null)
            {
                PairedDevices.Remove(matched);
            }

            PairedDevices.Add(args);
        });
    }

    private void _watcherPaired_EnumerationCompleted(DeviceWatcher sender, object args)
    {
        _watcherPaired.Stop();
    }

    private void InvokeThread(Action action)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            action();
        }, new System.Threading.CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness, _threadContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your closest bet: http://blog.falafel.com/bluetooth-rfcomm-communication-with-a-windows-iot-core-device/

It's a fairly old post since the term UWA is being used, but the concept is what you are looking for.

Use this code as the starting point and migrate it over to UWP to be able to use the Bluetooth Rfcomm Windows Runtime API: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Rfcomm-Chat-afcee559

Edit: Here is the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270289.aspx

Comment: I would like to thanks you for your help! But I need a very long time to understand and build it for my Project and to test it...

Comment: Indeed, but the answer lays in the links above showing you the right path to dig into. You might want to close this thread.

Comment: I just started reading your links. My question was "Is it possibe to paire a bluetooth device under Windows IoT Core programmatically?" And now my question is: Can you show me in your links where a unpaired Bluetooth device is paired programmatically??? :(