# UWP Unpaired Paired Bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am developing in Visual Studio 2015 in C# for
a Raspberry PI 2 device running Windows IoT Core.

For my application I need to pair and unpair Bluetooth devices.
Can I get a list with paired / unpaired / all Bluetooth devices?
Like what can be seen on the Bluetooth page of the
built-in management website (http://[deviceip]:8080/bluetooth.htm)

I found a example (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples),
but this is to much for me!

For now I just want to get a list with paired / unpaired Bluetooth devices

Comment: The examples can be overwhelming at first, I took what I learned from them and answered below. I also restructured / rephrased your question a little, please take no offence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find devices (Bluetooth or otherwise) you need a `selector`
which can be used to tell the `DeviceWatcher` the type of device to search for.

These `selectors` are basically strings identifying the type of device,
and the UWP framework provides some of them through methods on various classes.

```
//Gets all paired Bluetooth devices
var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelector();

//Gets all paired Bluetooth devices (same as above as far as I can tell)
var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true);

//Gets all unpaired Bluetooth devices
var selector = BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false);
```

From the samples on GitHub:

> Currently Bluetooth APIs don't provide a selector to get ALL devices 
>   that are both paired and non-paired. Typically you wouldn't need this
>   for common scenarios, but it's convenient to demonstrate the 
>   various sample scenarios.

Why we wouldn't typically need this is beyond me, but they do provide 
a selector which can be used to find both paired and unpaired devices:

```
var selector = 
        "System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}\"";
```

Once you have this `selector` you need to create an instance
of the `DeviceWatcher` class using a method on the `DeviceInformation` class:

```
var deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(selector, 
                       null, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
```

Finally you have to hook up the events so you get notified of changes:

```
deviceWatcher.Added += (s, i) => { //Handle the new device };
deviceWatcher.Updated += (s, i) => { //Handle the updated device };
deviceWatcher.Removed += (s, i) => { //Handle the removed device };
deviceWatcher.Completed += (s, a) => { s.Stop(); };
deviceWatcher.Stopped += (s, a) => { //Handle here };
```

Notice that in the `Completed` handler I stopped the `DeviceWatcher`
so it enters the `Stopped` state and can be started again.

Once you have the `DeviceInformation` you can pair as follows:

```
var pairingResult = 
    await i.Pairing.PairAsync(DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption);
```

As for unpairing, you need to make sure your project targets `Build 10586`
or any later version in the project properties windows:

[image: Project Properites]

Then you'll be able to call `UnPairAsync`:

```
await i.Pairing.UnpairAsync();
```

Older builds do not support [UnpairAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformationpairing.unpairasync.aspx%22MSDN%22).